# Updating values in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column called `IdNumber` in my `Client` table. Each client was assigned an `IDNumber` of `ID100` (and it increments by one every time I add a new client). I had to add an `A` to the end of it, so all new values are `ID100A`, `ID101A`, `ID102A` and so on.

How would I go about updating all the old ID's so that they have the `A` added to it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you meant how to update existing values:

```
UPDATE ClientTable
SET IDNumber = IDNumber + 'A'
```

EDIT Just in case

```
WHERE IDNumber NOT LIKE '%A'
```

END EDIT

Of course you should not exceed column length

Otherwise if you have to insert new values:

```
DECLARE @MaxValue nvarchar(64)
DECLARE @NewValue nvarchar(64)
DECLARE @CurValue int
SELECT @MaxValue = MAX(IDNumber) FROM ClientTable
SELECT @CurValue = CONVERT (SUBSTRING(@MaxValue, 2, LEN(@MaxValue) - 3), int)
SELECT @NewValue = 'ID' + CONVERT(nvarchar(61), @CurValue) + 'A'
```

cannot test right now, but it should work

Comment: yes, since he said he has to add an 'A' to the end of existing values

Comment: He said *update all the old ID's so they have the 'A' added* which I believe means updating **only** those entries that don't have an `A` at the end yet - and leave those alone that already do

Comment: I only had 2 values with A already added to it, but hundreds of values with no A, so i kind of cheated and did it manually.

Comment: @marc_s I'm trying to understand your point, may be I'm missing something, but I'd say that before starting to add new values, all the existing ones can be considered old, isn't it?